# How to approach questions/users who ask good questions but accept only highly accurate answers

Tags: discussion, support

I have been answering questions in the `mongodb` tag especially which involves the aggregation framework. I do a lot of research and analysis before posting an answer since I want to make sure the answer i post is correct and also most of the questions always have more than one way to approach.

Sometimes I miss out on handling the syntactical differences in different versions of `mongodb`.

Am I wrong at expecting the question owner to change subtle syntax  by himself after looking into the documentation and using the correct syntax for his version?

In One of such instances, the post owner accepted the solution, but again took it back since it had a very minor syntax error, which if he wanted could have resolved by himself.

Most of the post owners there are newbies and I want to know a proper way/channel of communicating this to them without affecting them in a bad way.

Comment: You can suggest that they edit the syntactic errors themselves. That's one of the functions of editing.

Comment: Well, you cannot force anyone to accept anything. All you can do is to comment